# change gridview background color if the value is empty

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

i have this problem to change gridview color if the value in gridview is empty. i generate gridview using templatefield. i used this code and it change all in gridview except for the header :

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        //change it according your cell number or find element
        if (e.Row.Cells[0].Text != "")
            e.Row.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
        else
            e.Row.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
    }


}
```

and this is my back code which i assign gridview :

```
 <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowDataBound" >
   <Columns>
     <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Request Date">
       <ItemTemplate><%#Eval("request_date")%></ItemTemplate>
         </asp:TemplateField>

     <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="A01">
         <ItemTemplate>
           <%#Eval("prod_line").ToString() == "A01" ? "Job Order:" 
           +Eval("jo_no") +"\n\n\n\n\nQuantity: "
           +Eval("qty")+"\n\n\n\n\nNeed by Date:" 
           +Eval("need_by_date")+"\n\n\n\n\nStatus: "
           +Eval("process_id") : ""  %>
         </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>

    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="A02">
      <ItemTemplate>
         <%#Eval("prod_line").ToString() == "A02" ?"Job Order: " 
           +Eval("jo_no") +"\n\n\n\n\nQuantity: "
           +Eval("qty")+"\n\n\n\nNeed by Date: "     
           +Eval("need_by_date")+"\n\n\n\n\nStatus: "+Eval("process_id") : ""   %>
     </ItemTemplate>
   </asp:TemplateField>

   <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="A03">
     <ItemTemplate>
       <%#Eval("prod_line").ToString() == "A03" ? "Job Order: " 
         +Eval("jo_no") +"\n\n\n\n\nQuantity: "
         +Eval("qty")+"\n\n\n\nNeed by Date: " 
         +Eval("need_by_date")+"\n\n\n\n\nStatus: "+Eval("process_id") : ""   %>
     </ItemTemplate>
   </asp:TemplateField>

   <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="A04">
     <ItemTemplate>
       <%#Eval("prod_line").ToString() == "A04" ? "Job Order: " 
         +Eval("jo_no") +"\n\n\n\n\nQuantity: "
         +Eval("qty")+"\n\n\n\nNeed by Date: " 
         +Eval("need_by_date")+"\n\n\n\n\nStatus: "+Eval("process_id") : ""   %>
     </ItemTemplate>
   </asp:TemplateField>

   <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="A05">
     <ItemTemplate>
       <%#Eval("prod_line").ToString() == "A05" ? "Job Order: " 
         +Eval("jo_no") +"\n\n\n\n\nQuantity: "
         +Eval("qty")+"\n\n\n\nNeed by Date: " 
         +Eval("need_by_date")+"\n\n\n\n\nStatus: "+Eval("process_id") : ""   %>
     </ItemTemplate>
   </asp:TemplateField>

   <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="A06">
     <ItemTemplate>
       <%#Eval("prod_line").ToString() == "A06" ? "Job Order: " 
         +Eval("jo_no") +"\n\n\n\n\nQuantity: "
         +Eval("qty")+"\n\n\n\nNeed by Date: " 
         +Eval("need_by_date")+"\n\n\n\n\nStatus: "+Eval("process_id") : ""   %>
      </ItemTemplate>
   </asp:TemplateField>

   <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="A07">
     <ItemTemplate>
       <%#Eval("prod_line").ToString() == "A07" ? "Job Order: " 
         +Eval("jo_no") +"\n\n\n\n\nQuantity: "
         +Eval("qty")+"\n\n\n\nNeed by Date: "      
         +Eval("need_by_date")+"\n\n\n\n\nStatus: "+Eval("process_id") : ""  %>
     </ItemTemplate>
   </asp:TemplateField>

   <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="A08">
     <ItemTemplate>
       <%#Eval("prod_line").ToString() == "A08" ? "Job Order: " 
         +Eval("jo_no") +"\n\n\n\n\nQuantity: "
         +Eval("qty")+"\n\n\n\nNeed by Date: " 
         +Eval("need_by_date")+"\n\n\n\n\nStatus: "+Eval("process_id") : ""   %>
     </ItemTemplate>
   </asp:TemplateField>

   <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="A09">
     <ItemTemplate>
        <%#Eval("prod_line").ToString() == "A09" ? "Job Order: " 
          +Eval("jo_no") +"\n\n\n\n\nQuantity: "
          +Eval("qty")+"\n\n\n\nNeed by Date: " 
          +Eval("need_by_date")+"\n\n\n\n\nStatus: "+Eval("process_id") : ""   %>
     </ItemTemplate>
   </asp:TemplateField>

   <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="A10">
     <ItemTemplate>
       <%#Eval("prod_line").ToString() == "A10" ?"Job Order: "
          +Eval("jo_no") +"\n\n\n\n\nQuantity: "
          +Eval("qty")+"\n\n\n\nNeed by Date: " 
          +Eval("need_by_date")+"\n\n\n\n\nStatus: "
          +Eval("process_id") : ""   %>
     </ItemTemplate>
   </asp:TemplateField>

   <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="A11">
     <ItemTemplate>
       <%#Eval("prod_line").ToString() == "A11" ? "Job Order: " 
         +Eval("jo_no") +"\n\n\n\n\nQuantity: "
         +Eval("qty")+"\n\n\n\nNeed by Date: " 
         +Eval("need_by_date")+"\n\n\n\n\nStatus: "
         +Eval("process_id") : ""   %>
     </ItemTemplate>
   </asp:TemplateField>

   <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="A12">
     <ItemTemplate>
       <%#Eval("prod_line").ToString() == "A12" ? "Job Order: " 
         +Eval("jo_no") +"\n\n\n\n\nQuantity: "
         +Eval("qty")+"\n\n\n\nNeed by Date: " 
         +Eval("need_by_date")+"\n\n\n\n\nStatus: "
         +Eval("process_id") : ""   %>
     </ItemTemplate>
   </asp:TemplateField>

   <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="A13">
     <ItemTemplate>
       <%#Eval("prod_line").ToString() == "A13" ?"Job Order: "
         +Eval("jo_no") +"\n\n\n\n\nQuantity: "
         +Eval("qty")+"\n\n\n\nNeed by Date: " 
         +Eval("need_by_date")+"\n\n\n\n\nStatus: "
         +Eval("process_id") : ""   %>
     </ItemTemplate>
   </asp:TemplateField>

   <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="A14">
     <ItemTemplate>
       <%#Eval("prod_line").ToString() == "A14" ? "Job Order: " 
         +Eval("jo_no") +"\n\n\n\n\nQuantity: "
         +Eval("qty")+"\n\n\n\nNeed by Date: " 
         +Eval("need_by_date")+"\n\n\n\n\nStatus: "
         +Eval("process_id") : ""  %>
     </ItemTemplate>
   </asp:TemplateField>

   <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="A15">
     <ItemTemplate>
       <%#Eval("prod_line").ToString() == "A15" ?"Job Order: "
         +Eval("jo_no") +"\n\n\n\n\nQuantity: "
         +Eval("qty")+"\n\n\n\nNeed by Date: " 
         +Eval("need_by_date")+"\n\n\n\n\nStatus: "
         +Eval("process_id") : ""   %>
     </ItemTemplate>
   </asp:TemplateField>

   <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="A16">
     <ItemTemplate>
       <%#Eval("prod_line").ToString() == "A16" ? "Job Order: " 
         +Eval("jo_no") +"\n\n\n\n\nQuantity: "
         +Eval("qty")+"\n\n\n\nNeed by Date: " 
         +Eval("need_by_date")+"\n\n\n\n\nStatus: "
         +Eval("process_id") : ""   %>
     </ItemTemplate>
   </asp:TemplateField>

   <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="A17">
     <ItemTemplate>
       <%#Eval("prod_line").ToString() == "A17" ?"Job Order: "
         +Eval("jo_no") +"\n\n\n\n\nQuantity: "
         +Eval("qty")+"\n\n\n\nNeed by Date: " 
         +Eval("need_by_date")+"\n\n\n\n\nStatus: "
         +Eval("process_id") : ""   %>
     </ItemTemplate>
   </asp:TemplateField>

   <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="A18">
     <ItemTemplate>
      <%#Eval("prod_line").ToString() == "A18" ? "Job Order: "
        +Eval("jo_no") +"\n\n\n\n\nQuantity: "
        +Eval("qty")+"\n\n\n\nNeed by Date: " 
        +Eval("need_by_date")+"\n\n\n\n\nStatus: "+Eval("process_id") : ""   %>
     </ItemTemplate>
   </asp:TemplateField>
  </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

and i got the output like this :

[image: image i got using above code]

but i want the output be like this :

[image: image that i want to appear]

Answer (score 1):

Look at this section of your code , you will find the problem

```
 if (e.Row.Cells[0].Text != "")
        e.Row.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
    else
        e.Row.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
```

You are setting background color of whole row ***[e.Row.BackColor]*** if cell is empty 

Set the color of cell in row 

Like this

```
e.Row.Cells[0].BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
```

You can apply your logic with it (whichever cell you wanna color)

Comment: oh i understand why that occur. but i want to color it if the there is no value in gridview column/row. how can i achieve that ?

Comment: so many ways , get the cell value , cast it as string and check for length or check for string.Empty

Comment: @NFH  if does help you than please upvote an mark as answer

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand the issue, your cell has no value but if you see it within your `RowDataBound` event handler by putting the breakpoint, you would probably see value like this `&nbsp;` instead of empty string.

You just need to slightly modify your condition within `RowDataBound` like this:

```
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Server.HtmlDecode(e.Row.Cells[1].Text).Trim()))
      e.Row.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
```

The value within your cell is `htmlEncoded`. You need to decode it using `Server.HtmlDecode`, after this your value will be `" "` string with a space that's why I used `Trim()` and finally checked whether that value is `null or empty`

This is tested solution and It will work.

Comment: i put this in the code and if the value also exist in gridview, it will still color that column. why ? i only want the empty column to be color